# seed file : syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I generate some seed content with a script and at the end I get something like this:

```
Article.create!(
  brand:"adidas",
  price:90.00,
  remote_image_url:"https:http://media-cache.placedestendances.com/image/37/2/867372.38.jpg",
  redirection:"http://adidas.placedestendances.com/mode-femme/baskets-basses-stan-smith-blanc/fiche-produit,1718648,1718649",
  tags:"c")
```

When I run `db:seed` I get that error for the `brand:"adidas"` line:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

The very weird thing is when I manually retype brand it's working fine ..

I have a ton of data for the database so I cannot do that manually for each. And I get the same error randomly for some other articles.

Any ideas?

```
seed = File.open('../seed.rb', 'w');
ARGV.each do |f|
    File.open(f, "r") do |f1|
      while line = f1.gets
        tab = line.split("\",\"");
        tab[1].tr!(' €', '').tr!(',','.').tr!('"', '')
        seed.write(
    "Article.create!(
    brand:#{tab[0][0..-1].downcase!}\",
    price:#{tab[1][0..-2]},
    remote_image_url:\"https:#{tab[2]}\",
    redirection:\"#{tab[3][0..-2]},
    tags:\"#{f[5..-5]}\")
    ")
      end
    end
end
```

as entry i have :

```
  "MANGO","19,99 €","http://media-cache.placedestendances.com/image/97/0/831970.38.jpg","http://mango.placedestendances.com/mode-femme/collier-en-chaines-fines--dore/fiche-produit,1755700,1755701"
```

and after i got :

```
Article.create!(
    brand:"mango",
    price:19.99,
    remote_image_url:"https:http://media-cache.placedestendances.com/image/97/0/831970.38.jpg",
    redirection:"http://mango.placedestendances.com/mode-femme/collier-en-chaines-fines--dore/fiche-produit,1755700,1755701",
    tags:"a")
```

EDIT : fixed there were hidden characters ( cat -e => Article.create!(brand:M-oM-;M-? "mango",$
)

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the parameters as explicit hash:

```
Article.create!({
  brand:"adidas",
  price:90.00,
  remote_image_url:"https:http://media-cache.placedestendances.com/image/37/2/867372.38.jpg",
  redirection:"http://adidas.placedestendances.com/mode-femme/baskets-basses-stan-smith-blanc/fiche-produit,1718648,1718649",
  tags:"c"
})
```

Comment: Is your line the first line in the seed file or are there others before it? And does it work, if you just type in the same thing by hand? (maybe there are some hidden characters, which we do not see, but which prohibit parsing)

Comment: it's the first line, when i delete it, it's working i am adding the script it's very short maybe it's gonna help

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your script. Have you tried retyping the exact same command by hand?

Comment: ok so i copy past the line to make a cat -e and i got Article.create!(brand:M-oM-;M-? "mango",$    so now i know what to do to fix thx for your answer !